# What is the name of this family of polytope?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm searching some litterature about a family of polytope, but I can't find the name of it, maybe you can help me.

I have $n$ points $(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^d$ with $\forall i, x_i \ge 0$ is in the positive orthan.

Now I define $A = \{ \sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_i | \forall i, t_i \in [0,1] \}$. I don't need $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i = 1$ !

What is the name of this ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it, it is a n-Zonotope :)